# random output extremely eradic, empty variable

Tags: javascript, random

My random generator makes names predominately to the large side. From what I read that can be a factor if you use .round, .ceil or .floor. It also it supposed to make a name no smaller than 3 and no larger than 13.

After adding the title to the name, some of the names were 2 and 14 and such, so I modified it again. Am I going the wrong way about this?
also how do you empty a var for recycling. everytime I try to recycle this and rerun it, it keeps adding to the original var

```
var nameLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 3) + 3); /* min 3 max 13*/
var compareLetter = 0;
var randomLetter = "";
var randomName = "";
var capitolLetter = "";
var checkLetter = 0;
var nameTitle = "XXX"; /* titles add _ between title and name*/
var nameLetters = [
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"],
    ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"],
    ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
];
if (nameTitle !== "") { /* my attempt to subtract title length +1 from name length if over 13*/
    nameLength = nameLength + (nameTitle.length + 1);
    if (nameLength > 13) {
        nameLength = nameLength - (nameLength - 13);
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < nameLength; i++) {
    randomLetter = nameLetters[compareLetter][Math.floor(Math.random() * nameLetters[compareLetter].length)];
    checkLetter = nameLetters[1].indexOf(randomLetter);
    if (checkLetter > -1) { /* my version of keeping consanants and vowels from stacking up */
        compareLetter = 2;
    } else {
        compareLetter = 1;
    }
    if (randomName.length < 1) { /* my version to keep first letter capitolized*/
        capitolLetter = randomLetter.toUpperCase();
        randomName = randomName + capitolLetter;
    } else {
        randomName = randomName + randomLetter;
    }
}
if (nameTitle !== "") {
    alert(nameTitle + "_" + randomName);
} else {
    alert(randomName);
}
alert(nameLength);
alert(randomName.length);
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not yet able to comment, so this will be a comment disguised as an answer...

1) Math.random() will return a zero, but will not return a 1 -- it returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). So using floor in this manner will never result in your upper bound being reached. Math.round would be a better choice. (This also goes for your later use of Math.random in selecting letters -- I don't think you'll get a "z" with this, but I haven't checked your math.)

2) The initial random nameLength calc is a bit tortured -- I follow it, but embedding (13-3) in the calculation is just awkward. Just make the calculation straightforward and comment accordingly.

```
 var nameLength = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) + 3
```

3) You may want to explain the nameTitle interaction with nameLength. I can't figure out what you're trying to accomplish there -- let's say, for example, your above calculation results in a nameLength of 8. Your nameTitle right now is hardwired as "XXX", so your calculation just alters the nameLength from 8 to 12. Basically, you're adding 4 to the nameLength until you would get to 13. That may be what you want, but why?

I don't know that any of the above are *the* reason you're seeing variable length values, but they may be contributors.